# Move title while scrolling the page

Tags: html

I would like to know if there is an HTML tag that can help me in scrolling the title along with the scroll bar? I have noticed in some of the posts it says POSITION:FIXED, but I am not sure how can I embeed it in html? Also, I am suppose to put these HTMLs inside JAVA code, so please help me out.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please add the relevant code that you're working on already so that somebody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the "position: fixed;" into your css. For example if your title is:

```
<h1 class="title">Title</h1>
```

your css has to be like:

```
.title {
    position: fixed;
}
```

If you dont't have a css file, you can use inline-styles:

```
<h1 style="position: fixed;">Title</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Since my code is embeded into Java as "orderSection.setTitleText("Order for " + desc);" Can I write <div style ="position: fixed;"/>.. along with "Order for" Will this work?

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer so I don't know how this function works but Iwould try to pass it something like `"<div style =\"position: fixed;\"/>Order for" + desc + "</div>"`